# Create vuejs reactive component for product variations (colors, size, ...) whithout losing the content on the already generated ones

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, e-commerce

I need to make a reactive component to create and update a form of product variations with their options, just like Shopify new product page, where you can add the options and values for a product, like color (red, blue, white), size(L,M,S), as many as you want, and bellow while you insert the options, you see on live the new variations being generated.
I managed to make something, but the way I did when I change any of the options or values of options, it re-renders all my components and reactive array that store my form values, and I lost for example a price I already had inserted on a variant already made.
[Shopify New Product Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8Yp3.jpg)
On the image, look that I already set some values like Price for a variation, and I can't lost that value when I need to add some other variation when another size are added for example, since I will just need to generate the new variations for that new size

CreateProduto.vue

```
<Variacoes 
:titulo="titulo" 
:custoAutomatico="custoAutomatico" 
:precoPorVariacao="precoPorVariacao" 
:pesoDimensaoPorVariacao="pesoDimensaoPorVariacao" 
class="-mb-5"
/>
```

Variacoes.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="flex grid overflow-hidden overflow-x-auto space-y-4 -mx-5 px-5 mt-2">

        <Atributos/>

        <!-- Variações -->
        <div>
            <div 
                v-for="variacao in storeLojaProdutos.formVariacoes" 
                :key="variacao.produto_variacao_id" 
                class="-mx-5 px-5 flex-wrap border-t border-slate-100 dark:border-slate-700 cursor-pointer hover:bg-slate-100"
                @click="variacaoEmEdicao = variacao; storeLojaProdutos.detalhesProdutoModal = !storeLojaProdutos.detalhesProdutoModal"
            >
                <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-between items-center py-2 grid md:grid-cols-12">
                    <span class="flex text-md font-semibold text-slate-700 md:col-span-9 dark:text-slate-300">{{ variacao.titulo }}</span>
                    <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-between gap-1 md:col-span-3">
                        <span class="md:w-full text-sm dark:text-slate-300">R$ {{ variacao.preco_varejo }}</span>
                        <span class="md:w-full text-sm dark:text-slate-300">Custo: R$ {{ variacao.custo }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- <span class="input-label border px-4 py-2 rounded">Editar</span> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <DetalhesProduto 
            :variacaoEmEdicao="variacaoEmEdicao" 
            :title="props.titulo"
            :custoAutomatico="props.custoAutomatico" 
            :precoPorVariacao="props.precoPorVariacao" 
            :pesoDimensaoPorVariacao="props.pesoDimensaoPorVariacao" 
        />

    </div>
</template>
<script setup>
import Atributos from "./Atributos.vue";
import DetalhesProduto from "./DetalhesProduto.vue";
import { useStoreLojaProdutos } from "@/store/loja/lojaProdutos";
import { computed, watch, watchEffect, ref } from "vue";

const props = defineProps(['titulo', 'custoAutomatico', 'precoPorVariacao', 'pesoDimensaoPorVariacao'])
const storeLojaProdutos = useStoreLojaProdutos();

let variacaoEmEdicao = ref(null);

// const validarVariacoes = computed(() => {})


// MONTAR AS VARIAÇÕES

const montarVariacoes = () => {
    if(storeLojaProdutos.atributosVariacoes.length == 0 || storeLojaProdutos.atributosVariacoes[0].valores[0].valor == '') {
        storeLojaProdutos.formVariacoes = []

    } else {
        let arrayAtributosValores = []
        let aux = []

        // Construir Array de arrays de cada um dos atributos e seus valores
        storeLojaProdutos.atributosVariacoes.forEach(atributo => {
            
            atributo.valores.forEach(valor => {
                aux.push({
                    atributo_id: atributo.atributo_id,
                    atributo: atributo.atributo,
                    valor_id: valor.valor_id,
                    valor: valor.valor
                })
            })
            
            arrayAtributosValores.push(aux)
            
            aux = []
        })

        const montar = (list, n = 0, result = [], current = []) => {
            if (n === list.length) result.push(current)
            else list[n].forEach(item => montar(list, n+1, result, [...current, item]))
            return result
        }

        let variacoes = montar(arrayAtributosValores)

        let response = variacoes.map(variacao => {

            let variac = {}

            // COM NOME PRODUTO PAI
            // let titulo = props.titulo
            // variacao.forEach(atributox => {
            //     titulo += ' ' + atributox.valor
            // })

            // SEM NOME PRODUTO PAI
            let titulo = ''
            variacao.forEach(atributox => {
                titulo += ' ' + atributox.valor
            })
            titulo = titulo.substring(1)
            
            
            variac.titulo = titulo
            variac.produto_variacao_id = null
            variac.preco_varejo = null
            variac.preco_varejoError = ''
            variac.preco_atacado = null
            variac.preco_atacadoError = ''
            variac.custo = null
            variac.custoError = ''
            variac.atributos = variacao

            return variac
        })

        storeLojaProdutos.formVariacoes = response

    }
}

montarVariacoes()

watch(() => [storeLojaProdutos.atributosVariacoes, props.titulo], ([newLoja, newTitulo]) => {
    console.log(newLoja, newTitulo)
    montarVariacoes()
},
{deep: true})

</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
</style>
```

Atributos.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="space-y-4">
            <div v-for="(atributo, i) in storeLojaProdutos.atributosVariacoes" :key="i" class="-mx-5 px-5 flex-wrap border-b border-slate-100 dark:border-slate-700">
                
                <!-- NÃO COLAPSADO -->
                <div v-show="!atributo.collapsed">
                    <div class="flex justify-between items-center">
                        <span class="input-label">Nome da Variação</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex justify-between space-x-2 items-center mb-2">
                        <div class="flex-1">
                            <InputGroup 
                                type="text" 
                                placeholder="Capacidade/Tamanho/Cor" 
                                v-model="atributo.atributo" 
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex-0 text-md">
                            <Tooltip placement="top" arrow theme="danger-500">
                                <template #button>
                                <button class="kanbanicon" @click="deletarAtributo(atributo)">
                                    <Icon icon="heroicons-outline:trash" />
                                </button>
                                </template>
                                <span> Deletar Variação</span>
                            </Tooltip>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <ValoresAtributo :atributo="atributo" />

                </div>

                <!-- COLAPSADO -->
                <div v-show="atributo.collapsed" class="flex justify-between items-center mb-3">
                    <div class="flex flex-wrap w-full">
                        <span class="input-label w-full">{{ atributo.atributo }}</span>
                        <div class="flex flex-wrap gap-2">
                            <span v-for="valor in atributo.valores" :key="valor.valor_id">
                                <Badge :label="valor.valor" badgeClass="bg-slate-800 dark:bg-slate-900 text-slate-800 dark:text-slate-400 bg-opacity-[0.12]" />
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <span class="input-label border px-4 py-2 rounded" @click="atributo.collapsed = !atributo.collapsed">Editar</span>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="flex flex-nowrap text-primary-500 items-center cursor-pointer -mx-5 px-5 -mb-5 py-5 space-x-4" @click.prevent="adicionarAtributo">
            <Icon icon="heroicons-outline:plus" />
            <span class="font-semibold">{{ storeLojaProdutos.atributosVariacoes.length > 0 ? 'Adicionar outra variação' : 'Adicionar variações como capacidade ou cor' }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import Button from "@/components/Button";
import InputGroup from "@/components/InputGroup";
import Icon from "@/components/Icon";
import Tooltip from "@/components/Tooltip";
import Badge from "@/components/Badge";
import ValoresAtributo from "./ValoresAtributo.vue";
import { useStoreLojaProdutos } from "@/store/loja/lojaProdutos";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import { ref } from "vue";

const storeLojaProdutos = useStoreLojaProdutos();

const adicionarAtributo = () => {
    storeLojaProdutos.atributosVariacoes.push({
        atributo_id: '',
        atributo: "",
        valores: [
            {
                valor_id: '',
                valor: ''
            },
        ],
        collapsed: false
    })
}

const deletarAtributo = (atributo) => {
    const index = storeLojaProdutos.atributosVariacoes.indexOf(atributo)
    storeLojaProdutos.atributosVariacoes.splice(index, 1);
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.kanbanicon {
  @apply border border-slate-200 dark:border-slate-700 dark:text-slate-400 rounded h-6 w-6 flex flex-col  items-center justify-center text-base text-slate-600;
}
</style>
```

ValoresAtributos.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="flex w-full justify-between">
            <span class="pl-3 input-label">Valores da Variação</span>
        </div>

        <div class="flex w-full justify-between">
            <draggable
                :list="props.atributo.valores"
                :animation="200"
                ghost-class="ghost-card"
                :group="props.atributo.atributo_id"
                :itemKey="props.atributo.atributo_id"
                class="pl-3 h-full w-full"
                handle=".handle"
            >
                <template #item="{ element }">
                    <div class="flex justify-between space-x-2 items-center mb-4">
                        
                        <!-- Handler -->
                        <div class="flex-0 text-md handle cursor-grabbing">
                            <Icon icon="radix-icons:drag-handle-dots-2" />
                        </div>

                        <!-- Input Valor -->
                        <div class="flex-1 w-full">
                            <InputGroup 
                                type="text" 
                                placeholder="Branco/Preto/Roxo" 
                                v-model="element.valor" 
                            />
                        </div>

                        <!-- ícone Lixeira -->
                        <div class="flex-0 text-md">
                            <Tooltip placement="top" arrow theme="danger-500">
                                <template #button>
                                <button class="kanbanicon" @click="deletarValor(props.atributo, element)" v-if="props.atributo.valores.length > 1">
                                    <Icon icon="heroicons-outline:trash" />
                                </button>
                                </template>
                                <span> Deletar Valor</span>
                            </Tooltip>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </template>
            </draggable>
        </div>

        <div class="flex items-center justify-between mb-2">
            <span class="input-label border px-4 py-2 rounded" @click="adicionarValor(props.atributo)">Adicionar outro valor</span>
            <span class="input-label border px-4 py-2 rounded" @click="props.atributo.collapsed = !props.atributo.collapsed">Pronto</span>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>
<script setup>
import draggable from "vuedraggable";
import InputGroup from "@/components/InputGroup";
import Icon from "@/components/Icon";
import Tooltip from "@/components/Tooltip";
import { useStoreLojaProdutos } from "@/store/loja/lojaProdutos";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

const storeLojaProdutos = useStoreLojaProdutos();

const props = defineProps(['atributo'])

const adicionarValor = (atributo) => {
    atributo.valores.push(
        {
            valor_id: '',
            valor: ''
        }
    )
}

const deletarValor = (atributo, valor) => {
    const index = atributo.valores.indexOf(valor)
    atributo.valores.splice(index, 1);
}

</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.kanbanicon {
  @apply border border-slate-200 dark:border-slate-700 dark:text-slate-400 rounded h-6 w-6 flex flex-col  items-center justify-center text-base text-slate-600;
}
</style>
```

DetalhesProdutos.vue

```
<template>
    <Modal
        :activeModal="storeLojaProdutos.detalhesProdutoModal"
        @close="storeLojaProdutos.detalhesProdutoModal = false"
        :title="variacaoEmEdicao ? title + ' ' + variacaoEmEdicao.titulo : 'Editar Variação'"
        centered
    >
        <div class="space-y-4">
            <Textarea 
                label="Descrição" 
                name="pn4" 
                placeholder="Descrição do produto" 
                v-model="variacaoEmEdicao.descricao" 
                :error="variacaoEmEdicao.descricaoError"
            />
            <div class="grid md:grid-cols-3 gap-4">
                <InputGroup 
                    label="Preço Varejo" 
                    type="number" 
                    placeholder="100" 
                    prepend="R$"
                    merged
                    v-model="variacaoEmEdicao.preco_varejo" 
                    :error="variacaoEmEdicao.preco_varejoError"
                />
                <InputGroup 
                    label="Preço Atacado" 
                    type="number" 
                    placeholder="100" 
                    prepend="R$"
                    merged
                    v-model="variacaoEmEdicao.preco_atacado" 
                    :error="variacaoEmEdicao.preco_atacadoError"
                />
                <InputGroup 
                    label="Custo por item" 
                    type="number" 
                    placeholder="" 
                    :prepend="custoAutomatico ? '' : 'R$'" 
                    merged
                    :disabled="custoAutomatico"
                    v-model="variacaoEmEdicao.custo" 
                    :error="variacaoEmEdicao.custoError"
                />
            </div>
            <div v-if="variacaoEmEdicao.preco_varejo && variacaoEmEdicao.custo">
                <hr>
                <div class="grid md:grid-cols-3 gap-4 mt-2">
                    <InputGroup 
                        label="Lucro Varejo" 
                        type="text" 
                        placeholder="" 
                        merged
                        disabled
                        :modelValue="'R$ ' + (variacaoEmEdicao.preco_varejo - variacaoEmEdicao.custo).toFixed(2)" 
                        :error="variacaoEmEdicao.preco_varejo - variacaoEmEdicao.custo < 0 ? 'Prejuízo' : ''"
                    />
                    <InputGroup 
                        label="Margem Varejo" 
                        type="text" 
                        placeholder="" 
                        merged
                        disabled
                        :modelValue="((variacaoEmEdicao.preco_varejo - variacaoEmEdicao.custo)*100/variacaoEmEdicao.preco_varejo).toFixed(2) + ' %'" 
                        :error="variacaoEmEdicao.preco_varejo - variacaoEmEdicao.custo < 0 ? 'Prejuízo' : ''"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div v-if="variacaoEmEdicao.preco_atacado && variacaoEmEdicao.custo">
                <hr>
                <div class="grid md:grid-cols-3 gap-4 mt-2">
                    <InputGroup 
                        label="Lucro Atacado" 
                        type="text" 
                        placeholder="" 
                        merged
                        disabled
                        :modelValue="'R$ ' + (variacaoEmEdicao.preco_atacado - variacaoEmEdicao.custo).toFixed(2)" 
                        :error="variacaoEmEdicao.preco_atacado - variacaoEmEdicao.custo < 0 ? 'Prejuízo' : ''"
                    />
                    <InputGroup 
                        label="Margem Atacado" 
                        type="text" 
                        placeholder="" 
                        merged
                        disabled
                        :modelValue="((variacaoEmEdicao.preco_atacado - variacaoEmEdicao.custo)*100/variacaoEmEdicao.preco_atacado).toFixed(2) + ' %'" 
                        :error="variacaoEmEdicao.preco_atacado - variacaoEmEdicao.custo < 0 ? 'Prejuízo' : ''"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <template #footer>
            <Button text="Editar" btnClass="btn-dark" @click="storeLojaProdutos.detalhesProdutoModal = false"></Button>
        </template>
    </Modal>
</template>

<script setup>
import Button from "@/components/Button";
import Modal from "@/components/Modal";
import InputGroup from "@/components/InputGroup";
import Textarea from "@/components/Textarea";
import Select from "@/components/Select";
import Alert from '@/components/Alert';
import { useField, useForm } from "vee-validate";
import { useStoreLoja } from "@/store/loja/loja";
import * as yup from "yup";
import { useToast } from "vue-toastification";
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import { ref } from "vue";
import { estadosBR } from "@/constant/data"
import { useStoreLojaProdutos } from "@/store/loja/lojaProdutos";

const props = defineProps(['variacaoEmEdicao', 'title', 'custoAutomatico', 'precoPorVariacao', 'pesoDimensaoPorVariacao']);
const storeLojaProdutos = useStoreLojaProdutos();

const route = useRoute();
const toast = useToast();

</script>
<style lang=""></style>
```